# how to degrade cassandra cluster to standalone

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I have setup cassandra cluster with two nodes, node1 and node2. node1 is the seed node.

I would like to decommission node2 from the cluster.

system auth config

```
KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

I have changed the config of my keyspace `my_data` from below

```
KEYSPACE my_data WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

to

```
KEYSPACE my_data WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

After changing the config, I have run a full repair on `system_auth` and `my_data`.

After decommissioning node2 using `nodetool -h node2 -pw somepassword -u someuser decommission`, I am getting the below error while connecting to node1 through cqlsh.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'node1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to node1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"',)})
```

I am using the same credentials but cannot log in. Can you please suggest the correct config to be changed and the process to do that?

Comment: I see two possibilities here: Either the user you're trying to log into didn't fully replicate to all nodes (maybe you created the user before you changed RF=2 on SYSTEM_AUTH and repair never ran), and you decommissioned the node that had the data, or your CL is higher than the node count for the authentication data. I'm almost thinking it's the first. Anyway, if it is the first (the node you decommed had the data, and remaining node does not), then you could disable authentication in the dse.yaml (assuming dse, but not sure) and then "fix" the user (alter user..). Are you using dse or apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After decommissioning node2, I have removed authentication to
   Cassandra server restarted the server.
2. This allowed me to connect to Cassandra, after that I have changed system_auth keyspace topology to SimpleStrategy with replication_factor of 1. Then I have repaired the system_auth keyspace
3. Then restarted Cassandra server and repaired the system_auth keyspace again.
4. Now I can connect with username and password.

Remove authentication process

```
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
```

Commands:-

```
nodetool -h nodetool -pw somepassword -u someuser decommission
nodetool repair system_auth
```